# Working with a vector of variables in dplyr. Is there any "any_of" equivalence in dplyr for not selecting?

Tags: r, dplyr

Regarding doing mutations and simple transformations not depending on variables with names that can be matched via "`starts_with`", "`ends_with`" etc, but just variables stored in a vector variable.

Is there a way, pe, to do transformations on the variables stored in a vector? I bet there is, but despise my efforts and consulting the list of dplyr functions I can't find it.

For now I have tried all the usual selectors like `any_of`, and `all_of`, but at the moment, they keep failing because it's not in a selecting method.

So. I'm stuck with this that doesnt work.

```
myvars = c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")
iris2 = iris %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(geo.mean= psych::geometric.mean(any_of(myvars)))

# It should do something like this:
iris %>%   rowwise() %>%
  mutate(geo.mean = psych::geometric.mean(c(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) )
```

I have also take a look at `pick()` but Im currently trying to reinstall dplyr in order to update it from my 1.0.1 to the 1.1.0 version to no avail. (It keeps telling me to restart the session despise there are no packages loaded that could prevent it to update, I'm currently on it). Thing is, from the documentation, its like a subset and I intend to keep all my variables.

Comment: Are you looking for `across`? `iris %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(geo.mean= across(all_of(myvars), psych::geometric.mean))
`

Comment: FYI, for your dplyr reinstall woes: also make sure no other R process is active that could be linking to dplyr's DLLs. The inability to replace a package can be associated with DLL file-locking, so multi-process possibility.

Comment: @Maël No, across generates a tibble there. I tried it but didnt get the expected results.

Comment: @r2evans Any way to be sure there are no other R process? I restarted even but to no avail, keeps the dplyr in my 1.0.1v.

Comment: Could you share your expected output? It's unclear atm

Comment: Done, @Maël.  Maybe now its more clear. The across one idk it generates a tibble instead of just a value for the column. Dplyr things I supose

Comment: If you are restarting R into a project, an `.Rprofile`, and/or with an `.Rdata` file, it could be autoloading packages. When you start your fresh R, check `sessionInfo()` to list all loaded and attached packages to verify dplyr is not among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the 'c_across()' function which lets you use tidy selection syntax:

```
iris %>%    
  rowwise() %>%    
  mutate(geo.mean = psych::geometric.mean(c_across(all_of(myvars))))
```